# Knockout.js Unobtrusive event handler not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Here is I have table built with knockout 'foreach'. After user select some rows, these rows will contain class 'success'. So I want to use self.create event that fire after user press button (button located outside element that ViewModel binded to) in order to handle such table rows. But Firebug said: **TypeError: GrafikViewModel.books is undefined**.
Here is the code:

```
function InfoViewModel(baseUri) {
    //some viewmodel here
}
 //This is viewmodel I'm talking about.
function GrafikViewModel(grafikUri) {
    var self = this;
    self.books = ko.observableArray();
    self.create = function () {
      //Here we will handle tr with class 'success'
        alert("!!!");
    }
    $.getJSON(grafikUri, function (data) {
        self.books(data.$values);
    });          
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = location.href.split("/");
    var baseUri;
    var tkod = url[5];
    if (url[4].toString = 'x') {
        baseUri = '/api/xTourist/' + tkod;
    }
    else if (url[4].toString = 'y') {
        baseUri = '/api/yTourist/' + tkod;
    }
    var grafikUri = '/api/grafik/' + tkod;
    ko.applyBindings(InfoViewModel(baseUri), document.getElementById('info'));
    ko.applyBindings(new GrafikViewModel(grafikUri), document.getElementById('grafik'));
    $('#book').click(function () {
      //Here I'm trying to call ViewModel.
        GrafikViewModel.books.create(ko.dataFor(this));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try **new** GrafikViewModel().books.create(ko.dataFor(this));

Comment: FireBug: TypeError: (intermediate value).books.create is not a function.

Comment: have you added the new keyword?

Comment: You are calling the create function on the books object, this will not work as the create function is declared in the GrafikViewModel viewModel. it should be new GrafikViewModel().create and not new GrafikViewModel().books.create